# Visual Studio 2013, Odd occurance of BC30969 when mixing languages

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

This may seem like a strange use case but it is legitimate in my code base.  I have a C++/CLI project "sandwiched" between two VB.NET projects.  For example, project C depends on (references) project M depends on project A1.  (Of course, in C there is an explicit reference to both M and A1).

C->M->A1

Where C and A1 are VB.NET and M is C++/CLI.

Also in the solution, and this is the strange part, there is a project A2 which is VB.NET and produces a dll by the same name as A1 (both produce A.dll).  There are no references to A2 by any other projects.  Regardless, when building, I get from project C:

> error BC30969: Reference required to assembly 'A, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' containing type 'A.Class1', but
>   a suitable reference could not be found due to ambiguity between
>   projects 'A1' and 'A2'.

My question is, why is there ambiguity between A1 and A2 when I only ever reference A1?  It seems that the mere presence of A2 causes this to happen.

Note that this doesn't happen unless, as in my case, M is C++/CLI.  If M is a VB.NET project, then this doesn't happen.

I have an example solution with project files that demonstrates this behavior.  I'd be happy to share it with anyone however I don't see how to attach a file to this post.

Comment: Post it to a file sharing service.  Be sure to keep it small.